# Secure way to update Firestore "balance" field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my app each user has a "balance" entry in Firestore that handles their in-app credits.

How can I update in a secure way their balances when they interact with the app?

At the moment I update the balance client-side, with `Firestore.collectio().document().update({...})` but I'm not sure if that is enough safe, even if I have Firestore rules and AppCheck enabled.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid problems, the ideal is that you make this update using a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions).

Remembering that it is good to avoid numbers with floating point, in case these credits are money.

Comment: I can't understand how using transactions would make safer the balance update. I guess they  still work client side, so the code could potentially be compromised

Comment: It depends on how you are performing this operation.

Let's say it's a store, he buys the product, you check if there is a balance, you add the product to his inventory and then you decrease the balance. If you do this block outside of a transaction, a malicious user can end the block at the right moment, perhaps by disconnecting the internet or terminating the application. That way he will get the item for free.

Comment: That's another good point to take care of. But still doesn't solve the issue of updating balance client-side. I think it would be safer to update it server side. But how could I implement this behaviour, triggered by user's actions?

Comment: You can use [firebase functions with firestore trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#writing-triggered_functions) or you can create a http cloud function to execute your logic.

Comment: I'll learn more about Firestore triggers that seem very powerful, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow only certain updates to the balance, you can usually enforce those in your security rules.

If you've tried that and can't get it to work, we can help better if you [show what you tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm already working with security rules. I'm just asking my self if they are enough/if they are the only way to secure the database. I have users that purchase an item, so I have to update their balance. Should I do it client-side as with the code I wrote in the questions or should I implement something different?

Comment: "should I" is something only you can answer, but: 1) yes, it *is* typically possible to secure transactional updates through security rules. 2) no, that is not the only way to implement secure transactional updates. e.g. you can also do them in a trusted environment (such as a server you control or Cloud Functions/Cloud Run) and use a transaction as GabrielNexT answered). Since there you know the code running is what you wrote, you don't need security rules.

Comment: Thank you. I'll read something more about firestore triggers